# How to show twitter feed using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to show My Twitter Feed horizontally using Jquery in my web page. How can i do it?

Comment: Torque, there are already some web parts available to show Twitter feeds like [Free Sharepoint Twitter Web Part](http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5794) and [SharePoint Twitter](http://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-twitter/), why you insist to use JQuery?

Comment: Thank You Arsalan,
But as per requirement I have to display tweets using Jquery only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you want is a "JQuery Twitter ticker" sounds funky!

Here is a good one I have used in the past: [**Zazar twitter ticker**](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/ztwitterfeed/)

You will just need to shove it in a webpart, which is easy to do.

Comment: Thanks Hugh,
My requirement is little bit different. I want to show twitter feed continuously scrolling not one by one.

Comment: All you have to do is change the ticker time so the delay is lower and it will continuously scroll. Or Google "Horizontal Twitter Ticker" because there are dozens.

Answer (score 0):

Also check [this jQuery plugin](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/),
Just put plugin file to some SharePoint library, like Style Library. Link it on page.
Add another file to library and put there code to display your twitter feed, you can see few examples of this code on site I suggested.
Then add content editor web part to page, where you want to see twitter and link it on properties to file with your jQuery JavaScript code.

One code sample for you:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".tweet").tweet({
      join_text: "auto",
      username: "seaofclouds",
      avatar_size: 48,
      count: 3,
      auto_join_text_default: " we said, ",
      auto_join_text_ed: " we ",
      auto_join_text_ing: " we were ",
      auto_join_text_reply: " we replied ",
      auto_join_text_url: " we were checking out ",
      loading_text: "loading tweets..."
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Anton,
    The jQuery Plugin you suggested is showing feeds in verical manner. I want to show it horizontally and continuous manner.